# Angular : loop over object and concatinate into a string

Tags: html, angular, angular2-directives, ngfor

i have this data :

```
"commercialRanges": [
      {
        "rangeId": "700",
        "rangeName": "POSTPAID"
      },
      {
        "rangeId": "500",
        "rangeName": "PREPAID"
      },
    ]
```

In my my vew i want to display the rangeNames as one continated , joined string like this : `POSTPAID,PREPAID`

i ve tried this :

```
      <div  *ngFor="let g of gammes.data.commercialRanges">
          {{g.rangeName}},
      </div>
```

But this resulted me such a view : (separated strings)

```
FIXE,
POSTPAID,
```

Which is wrong ,

**suggestions ?**

Comment: may be it's a css issue, like  inline display

Comment: Why not simply you can do without loop if you've fixed data? `<div>{{gammes.commercialRanges[0].rangeName}}, {{gammes.commercialRanges[1].rangeName}}</div>`

Answer (score 3):

You could pre-process the data in your component and just display that:

```
this.rangeNames = games.data.commercialRanges.map(range => range.rangeName).join(",")

<div>{{ rangeNames }}</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple things you could do. You could just use the `join` function and display the result. Or you could display the text inline.

Join:

```
<div>
  {{games.data.commercialRanges.map(({rangeName}) => rangeName).join(', ')}},
</div>
```

Inline:

```
<div>
  <span *ngFor="let g of gammes.data.commercialRanges">
    {{g.rangeName}},
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, 
the above code separate on all the records or only the *rangeName* filed only?

Comment: Yep sorry. I missed that it was an  array of objects. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Use following code:

```
<span  *ngFor="let g of gammes.data.commercialRanges">
          {{g.rangeName}},
      </span>
```

div is block level element. So it will use a block. That's why view looks like that.

You can also also use your code like this:

```
<div  *ngFor="let g of gammes.data.commercialRanges" style="display: inline-block">
          {{g.rangeName}},
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the line break is because you are using divs and not spans, as divs are not inline by default.

Instead of using a for loop, can you not just display

```
{{gammes.data.commercialRanges.map(range => range.rangeName).join(", ")}}
```

This should also mean you do not get an extra , at the end

Comment: Wouldn't this display `[object Object],[object Object]`?

Comment: Sorry, yes you are right it would. You'd need to use map as others have above. I've changed that now